# Do loop trouble with label inside Do Loop

Tags: vb.net

So I am creating this multiplication table with a do loop. I just can't figure out how to print the times table to the label i have on the form. If i add some words outside of the loop it will show just fine but not inside the loop. Is their a way to post the results that i want each time the loop iterates through?

```
    Dim time As Integer
    Dim userNum As Integer
    Dim i As Integer = 1

    lblTable.Text = "Do Loop: " & vbNewLine

    Do Until i <= 10

        userNum = Integer.Parse(txtNumber.Text)


        If i <= 10 Then
            time = userNum * i
            lblTable.Text = userNum & " * " & i & " = " & time & vbNewLine

        End If
        i += 1
    Loop
```

Comment: Read `Do Until i <= 10` out loud to yourself and then ask yourself what that actually does.  I also suggest that you learn how to debug, i.e. set breakpoints and step through your code.  There's a good beginners tutorial [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/vbNet.html) and it has a section debugging.

Comment: By the way, what do you suppose is going to happen to the old value when you set the `Text` of a `Label`?  Also, how does your `If` statement make sense, given you `Do` condition? You really need to pick up a pen and paper and write down what your code is supposed to do, because what you have really makes little sense.

Comment: I would also suggest that a `For` loop would be more appropriate than a `Do` loop in this case, unless this is a learning exercise and you're required to use a `Do` loop. Unfortunately, many learning exercises are very contrived.

Comment: yes it is a learning exercise. I have done the for loop one which works just fine but not having good luck with do loops

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `While` and `Until`? They mean the same in the context of a `Do` loop as they do in plain English.